# User suddenly can't get past launch image screen

Tags: ios, crash

A user has reported that my app suddenly won't launch on their device.  They sent me a video, and they launch the app, the launch image screen shows for a split second, but then crashes back to the iOS home screen.

The user tried deleting and reinstalling the app with no benefit.

I use Crashlytics, and am not getting any reports of crashes from them (or any other user- although I've seen them in prior versions so I know it's working correctly). I'm also not seeing any crashes in iTunes connect.

I asked the user to send me any crash reports in the Settings Diagnostics section and they said there are none listed for my app.

I have confirmed that their iOS version is supported by my app. (iOS 8.4).

I'm not sure where to go next, and would appreciate any pointers. Sorry for the vague question but I have posted everything that I know about the situation.

Comment: is it working at your end? are you calling any webservice at launch of application, check what will happen if it gives error, make sure you calling all UI related code from main thread, including showing uialertview.

Comment: It is working for everyone but one user (as far as I'm aware).

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions sets up Flurry analytics as well as Crashlytics.  Both of these are boilerplate code from the particular source, and again work for everyone but this one user.

Comment: then it might be issue with that particular device, you can request user to try app once by restarting his device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to provide some closure on this. The user ended up wiping and restoring their device, and it solved the problem. It seems extreme to me but it was their own suggestion and didn't take them long to do. So I'm not sure what caused this but that's one (albeit brute force) way to fix it.